# python selenium: щелкнуть на ссылке, закрытой всплывающим окном

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, click

Подскажите, как разобраться со следующей ситуацией:

есть `<div>` нажатие на который вызывает необходимый скрипт, однако над ним стоит всплывающее окно и при выполнении

```
my_div.click()
```

вываливается ошибка, что на этих координатах находится другой объект

Как все таки выполнить нажатие на данный объект?

Конечном можно слегка промотать страницу, если нажатие не происходит - но это всё вероятностное решение и опять же, как по мне, требует лишнего кода (например всё завернуть в `try..exept`

А есть ли возможность без дополнительных операций отправить `div` сообщение "на тебя нажали мышкой"

Comment: В том и дело, что Селениум работает как надо, как реальный пользователь, и это хорошо для тестов. А вы хотите сделать хак. Поэтому нужно либо проматывать, либо через скрипт убирать это окно.

Comment: но если я не знаю что это за окно?
можно ли вместо ошибки получить объект, который закрывает? тогда его можно было бы убрать

Comment: Как вариант - кликнуть через JS, его тоже можно запускать из Selenium `driver.execute_script(...)`. Голый JS: `var link = document.getElementById('my-link'); link.click();`.  jQuery: `$(selector).click()`.

Comment: да, как вариант, но только в случае, если у элемента есть `id`, а если только `class`? временно назначить ему `id` и нажать через скрипт?

Comment: У яваскрипта есть разные варианты поиска - по классу, по Xpath, по атрибутам и т.п. Посмотрите, если класс уникальный, то можно напрямую найти кнопку `document.getElementsByClassName("...")[0].click()`. Если нет, то можно через поиск по вложенности, например через jQuery это `$(".block .button").click()` - найдет вложенный в класс block кнопку с классом button. Через либы типа jQuery проще искать, чем нативно на JS, а через селениум можно подрубить ее, если ее еще нет.

Comment: да, так и сделал! я только `querySelectorAll` использую, так что старье то можно уже не использовать типа `getElementsByClassName` и jQuery